# The performance impact of removing elements from the front of the slice

Tags: go, slice

I am moving from C++ to Golang and have a clarification question about slice in Golang.

I am trying to understand/confirm if it is an expensive operation to remove an element located at the front of the slice.

From the below example, it looks like the slice (frontRemoved) is still pointing to the original slice even after the removal of the first element. So, I think it is not an expensive operation to remove an element from the front of the slice (unlike vector in C++).

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
    original := []int {1,2,3,4}
    frontRemoved := original[1:]
    frontRemoved[0] = 10 
    fmt.Println("original slice:", original)
    fmt.Println("frontRemoved slice:",frontRemoved)
}
```

```
**Output**:
original slice: [1 10 3 4]
frontRemoved slice: [10 3 4]
```

Can you please let me know if it is an expensive operation to remove the first element of the slice?
Also, should I use a container/list to implement a queue? Or slice is an acceptable solution where performance is important?

Thank you

I have experimented with the above code to understand the slice implementation.

Comment: Slices in Go, use an array as the backing store. In your example shown, the sub-slice you created uses the same backing array. The backing array remains in memory, as long as there is a reference for it (either from the original or the sub-slices). But this is too trivial an operation to benchmark slice performance of slices. Edit your question to elaborate more on what sort of performance is intended

Comment: [1/2] To add to what other commenters said, I would look at your problem at a different angle: the (sub)slicing operation you've presented—`original[1:]` did the following: took the original slice value (a `struct` value containing the address of the backing array, the length and the capacity) and produced another slice value which has len and cap smaller by 1, and the address pointing at the beginning of the then-1st slice element. This operation in itself is super fast as could be guessed from my description but there are two observation to make about it _and think them through:_

Comment: [2/2] 1) The original element at index 0 did not "disappear"; it's still allocated in the original memory block, just inaccessible via the new slice value. 2) If you have a slice of N elements and then continue to "pop out" elements from its beginning using this subslicing technique until you have a slice containing only the element which was the last in the original slice, _all the slice's memory originally allocated is still allocated._ All-in-all, I recommend to read [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) then [this](https://blog.golang.org/slices)–it should have you covered on slices

Answer (score 0):

In Golang, removing an element from the front of the slice is not an expensive operation. In your example, Go doesn't create a new underlying array. Instead, it creates a new slice header that points to the same array but with different starting index.

So you're not copying elements around memory, you're just adjusting slice header's starting point and length.

For your second question, if your queue's size is fixed and you don't do much insertions or deletions in the middle, then using slice is fine.

But if your queue dynamically resize with much elements and you do a lot of insertions/deletions then you can use container/list as you mention.